# What is the confidence interval of chance of rain in weather forecasts?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, confidence-interval

When we look for the chance of rain today or the next hour, how do we interpret the percentage provided by weather forecasts? What is the confidence interval used here?

Is it the usual 95% as we study in books or is it different? if it is why and why not other intervals, say 99%?

[image: Please check the marked area]

Comment: I rarely see confidence intervals provided with weather reports. Do you have an example of this?

Comment: I don't either. I was checking the weather app and it says "Chance of Rain: 20%". I have been working on forecasting project reports, I always use confidence intervals. I am wondering why weather apps don't provide any confidence interval.

Comment: What is the definition of chance of rain in terms of amount of rain and exact location?

Comment: @ Michael Chernick Yes, it's not clear what the event is for which the probability (estimate) is being provided.  Anyhow, 50% + or - 50% at least doesn't undercover (except when we're 110% sure if will rain).

Comment: Edit: Added screenshot of the weather app for NYC and highlighted the section on rain and humidity.

Comment: Note that your screenshot does not include a CI.

Comment: @gung No, it doesn't. That is basically why I am asking this question.